# Verify files AFTER extracting gzip

Tags: compression, gzip

I gzip a folder, transfer it to a remote location and then extract it to a folder. The problem is that this machine is a little unreliable and sometimes writes don't succeed and there can be zero-byte files or corrupted files (I verified the archive was correct and subsequent extractions worked fine).

I know that gzip files have CRC info in them, so I'm wondering if there's an easy way to do this:

1. Download gzip
2. Extract gzip
3. Compare files on disk to gzip CRCs to verify extraction succeeded

Answer (score 0):

gzip already checks it.

```
if ! gunzip FILENAME 
  echo "crc error"
fi
```

Comment: I'm having a lot of trouble confirming what you're saying. I can't see any docs which show that. I don't want to check that the file is valid within the archive, I wanted to check that the file on disk matches what is in the archive.

Comment: huh? gzip is not an archive.

Comment: returning non-zero (which means false) on error is pretty standard for all *nix commands. gzip follows that